# Tropico 3 starting build order?

Tags: tropico-3

What's a good starting build order for a Tropico 3 Sandbox game?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good general avatar build for Tropico 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/what-is-a-good-general-avatar-build-for-tropico-3)

Comment: What's the difference with your other question ?

Comment: @MarmouCorp This is about building buildings, edicts, etc.  The other question is about what traits to choose for your [avatar](http://news.bigdownload.com/2009/06/18/tropico-3-reveals-avatar-features/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually play as "nice" Presidente.

To keep people content for the first election, I build a pub and a small medical service.
Both building help a lot to raise happiness, they've got a small footprint which means they will be built fast, and the pub enables the Mardi Gras edict, which can help a lot if the upcoming vote is going too close to call.

Build your favorite uneducated money makers and roads that leads to them with the remainder of the money.

Once you've got more money, build a couple of tenements, to house a big chunk of your population, and prepare your industry - higher level tourism