# What is a good general avatar build for Tropico 3?

Tags: tropico-3

What is a good build for most situations in Tropico 3?  I don't want to tweak my avatar for every map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to say, how do you want to play? Frankly there is no best build for every situation, the best you can hope for is to pick things that'll you need for every map, tourism/money/food. Things of that nature.

Ultimately, play how you want, your skill is more important than your avatars.